# Got an error with Junit platform v.5.8.1 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.commons.util.AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit5, spring-test

I run into an issue with this code:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ApiRestControllerTest {

  private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @InjectMocks
  private ApiRestController apiRestController;

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
        .standaloneSetup(apiRestController)
        .build();
  }

  @Test
  void shouldReturnsVersion() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/version"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(content().json(OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(new VersionResponse(VERSION))));
  }
}
```

I got an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.commons.util.AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;Z)Ljava/util/Optional;
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.DisplayNameUtils.getDisplayNameGenerator(DisplayNameUtils.java:110)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.DisplayNameUtils.lambda$createDisplayNameSupplierForClass$2(DisplayNameUtils.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.DisplayNameUtils.determineDisplayName(DisplayNameUtils.java:88)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterTestDescriptor.<init>(JupiterTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.<init>(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:96)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.<init>(ClassTestDescriptor.java:51)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.ClassSelectorResolver.newClassTestDescriptor(ClassSelectorResolver.java:119
```

I use JUnit **5.8.1**, but for lower versions, like 5.7.2 it works fine,

Comment: Most probably a version mismatch. Please post your full Gradle or Maven build file.

Answer (score 7):

The missing method `org.junit.platform.commons.util.AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(Class<?>, Class<A>, boolean)` was introduced in JUnit Platform 1.8.

So, you need to make sure that you upgrade to `junit-platform-commons` 1.8.1.

Using the `junit-bom` will help to simplify such upgrades to ensure you use compatible versions of all JUnit 5 artifacts.

Comment: Thank you that did it for me. Leaving this note for other potential readers: my parent Maven project dependency management specified `org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine` and `org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api` individually. Changed to `org.junit:junit-bom` and the error got away. The [example project](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/main/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven/pom.xml) should be a good reference.